# Too large vertical space in the list of *my* sites

Tags: bug, android-app

When edit list of my sites I see too large vertical space between already added sites:

[image: vertical space]

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: LGE
- Device Model: LG-D802
- OS Version: 5.0.2 (152331922a212)